# Any ideas why baking my normal map is failing?

Tags: baking, normal-map, artifacts

I am attempting to bake a normal map from a high poly to low ply model. I've unwrapped the low poly and I've checked selected to active. For some reason all I am getting is the yellow and green artifacts with ZERO proper normal mapping.

Here is the low poly model

[image]

Here is the high poly model

[image][image]

Here are the Normal Bake settings

[image]

And here is the normal map result

[image]

I've tried adjusting the Max Ray Distance and extrusion. I am selecting the high poly THEN the low so it is baking from selected to active correctly. I'm going nuts. Any thoughts, tips or ideas would be HUGELY appreciated.

Comment: if the face is completly parallel or perpendicular to the baking face it won't be baked as baking save the faces direction. Also there may be a normal orientation problem here but please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Here it is. https://pasteall.org/blend/6a23b7c0b2864e42bd8a9667a3a3196d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the *Extrusion* at 0.1 and the *Max Ray Distance* at 0. Now you still can't bake anything because the ray doesn't hit any surface as the faces that need to be baked are currently either perpendicular or parallel to the baking faces. Baking the normals save the normals of the faces, i.e. their direction, if the faces are perpendicular or parallel to the ray, nothing will be baked. To be able to bake something you need to tilt the faces a bit, for example you won't be able to bake this, but you'll be able to bake this:

[image]

[image]